# Missing time created in R

Tags: r, time

I am trying to create a time sequence variable of 15 minutes interval. My code is

```
seq(as.POSIXct("2018-03-11 02:00:00"),as.POSIXct("2018-03-11 03:45:00"),by=900 )
```

This doesn't create all the time points. Especially these:
"2018-03-11 02:00:00" "2018-03-11 02:15:00" "2018-03-11 02:30:00" "2018-03-11 02:45:00"

Further, if I want to read these values from a string variable using as.POSIXlt (formatted as "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"), only values at these specific time point is regarded as NA values. Other values are read perfectly well. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating a time series in R with a row every 15 minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43149953/creating-a-time-series-in-r-with-a-row-every-15-minutes)

Comment: The times you quoted above occurred during the transition from Standard time to daylight savings time thus they never existed.