# Generate a list of string csv names with 15 minutes time interval and today date

Tags: r, datetime

I am trying to find a way to create a list of csv names with today's date and every 15 minutes interval (0000, 0015, 0030, 0045, 0100, 0115, .... ).

I think I can get today date through `Sys.Date()` but how do I get the every 15 minutes interval?

```
data_20210827000000.csv
data_20210827001500.csv
data_20210827003000.csv
...
data_20210827234500.csv
```

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/q/43149953/680068

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
you could use something like this. If you want you could also add seconds.

library(stringi)

date <- gsub("-", "", Sys.Date())

Hours <- str_pad(string = rep(seq(0, 23, 1), each = 4), width= 2, side = c("left"), pad = "0")
Minutes <- str_pad(string = rep(seq(0, 45, 15), 24), width= 2, side = c("left"), pad = "0")

paste0("data_", date,Hours, Minutes, ".csv")
```